# Add PayPal payment button to the form

Tags: paypal, cognito-forms

How might I add a PayPal payment button to my Cognito form?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. We are in the final stages of testing a new payment feature that will be released soon. This new feature will use [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) as our payment processor, which will allow you to manage all of your payments within Cognito Forms. We are excited about this new release and will let all of our users know as soon as the new features are ready to use.

Comment: We have released our payment feature! This will allow users to collect payments with their Cognito Forms.